# What can I do to stop unwanted emails from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, bug, email

I am receiving unwanted emails from Stack Overflow.  The unsubscribe link in the email doesn't work.  Can I unsubscribe another way?

Comment: You will find it in the profile settings

Comment: [Meta.SE on how to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature)

Comment: Clarify _the unsubscribe link doesn't work_. That link should direct you to a place where you can manage email preferences. Does it not do that for you? Have you disabled all emails listed there, but do you still receive mails?

Comment: **This site can’t be reached**  
  
sg-links.stackoverflow.email’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: @user3208340 I'm going through some of the older bug reports. Were you able to get this resolved or are you still receiving The Overflow newsletter despite trying to unsubscribe?

Answer (score 4):

You can control your email settings from your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

This is what you find there:

[image]

Put everything in the off mode there.

Alternatively some emails do have an unsubscribe link but there was at least one report where clicking that link ended in an error.

Comment: everything is off.  I'm receiving regular emails for The Overflow newsletter.

Comment: @user3208340 you also clicked the suboptions like: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/digests/current